An unknown encoding error occurred while using ffmpeg
ffmpeg  -i D:\test.mp4 -threads 5 -c:a amr_wb -ar 16000 -ac 1 -y D:\test_wb.amr
error:Unknown encoder 'amr_wb'
When I see configuration:--enable-libopencore-amrwb, why do I still get an error

it is decoder only ffmpeg -codecs
